# Trying to create an application using youtube api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

If I was trying to access the video details of a video once a user with my app clicks a video. Is this possible. I see the resource activities goes based on actions. Is a video clicked by a user considered an action? The resource video allows you to access a videos description but I need the description of the video selected by the user at that time.

I thing the resource activities or video will help but I am unsure

Comment: I don't fully understand your question. youtube api has an endpoint for that, `https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos` .  Passing a videoID does the job...

Comment: Yes videoID will allow you to get the video description, but I am trying to get the video description of whatever video a user clicks in real time. Like I have a app and when you download it you allow me access to the videos you watch. When you click a video I would like access to video description of the whatever video you chose. Is this possible without hard coding a specific video? @pierpy

Comment: Of course it's possible. Try to code something, rendering various divs in a loop for example. Inside the loop, with titles, duration etc you can pass videoID to a function that populates the player. Very simple.